# Is it possible via DNS to point a subdomain of a website to a subdomain of another website?

Tags: domain-name-system

Assuming two different hosts, is it possible to point `a.site1.example` so that it serves up `b.site2.example`?

When someone visits `a.site1.example` I want them to see what is hosted at `b.site2.example`

What is the DNS required on each site to do this?

Comment: Whats your goal ? and do you own both site ? Imagine someone that do that on a banking site..

Comment: Depends on what you mean with "reflects `b.site2.com`". Do you want to serve a website? Do you want the user to be aware that he's redirected? A little more info would be nice.

Comment: @Broco, re-worded. I want it to serve up the site.

Comment: @yagmoth555 I own the site that will be served up (b.site2.com), and want to allow other others the ability to host it on their own subdomain.

Comment: Just because I don't think it's clear, `a.site1.com` can never just "serve up" `b.site2.com` solely through DNS -- sites are served over HTTP. At best, you will be able to provide a method for `a.site1.com` to *point at* `b.site2.com`, and allow `b.site2.com` to respond for it. All resources required for the site to exist will still rely on `b.site2.com`. If you actually want `a.site1.com` to be its own server serving up `b.site2.com` that would be through an HTTP daemon like Apache providing a reverse proxy, which `a.site1.com` would point to

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by using a CNAME for `a.site1.example` and point it to `b.site2.example`

You will have to accept requests for both `b.site2.example` and `a.site1.example` at `b.site2.example` because there will not be any HTTP redirects.

The client will do somethink like this.

1. Whats the ip for `a.site1.example`
2. The client will get the answer `b.site2.example`
3. The client will ask for the IP of `b.site2.example`
4. The client will connect to the IP of `b.site2.example` 
   and send the http host header with the hostname `a.site1.example`

Comment: You may run into a problem if there is an existing A-Record for a.site1.com

Answer (score 0):

Configure a webserver answering requests for `https://a.site1.example` which will return HTTP redirects for any URL and pointing to `https://b.site2.example`.

DNS wise this means that both names must resolve (through A/AAAA/CNAME records) to the correct servers, the same one or separate ones (your question lacks details)

If you do not want people to see the new URL then the first webserver needs to be configured as an HTTP proxy. This comes with various drawbacks, including performance loss to start with, but again your question lacks specific details.